# Using Boolean indexing to change value

Tags: python, dataframe, boolean

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
VendorAccount   FiscalPeriod    LCC
729616,             1,          False
729616,             2,          False
0,                  2,          False
1,                  4,          False
```

I attempted to use this line:

```
df['LCC'][(df['VendorAccount'] == 729616) & df['FiscalPeriod'] >1] = True
```

to make it look like this:

```
VendorAccount   FiscalPeriod    LCC
729616,             1,          False
729616,             2,          True
0,                  2,          False
1,                  4,          False
```

The script runs but no changes are being made. Can anyone advise me on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` operator has higher precedence than `>`, hence your original code is equivalent to this:

```
df['LCC'][((df['VendorAccount'] == 729616) & df['FiscalPeriod']) > 1] = True
```

To update the dataframe correctly you should use the following code instead:

```
df['LCC'][(df['VendorAccount'] == 729616) & (df['FiscalPeriod'] > 1)] = True
```